# How to plot descion boundary for three classes in logistic regression?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, classification

I would like to draw decision boundary for iris data with three classes. But, I do not know how to plot it.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

x_index = 0
y_index = 1

formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(lambda i, *args: iris.target_names[int(i)])

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
plt.scatter(iris.data[:, x_index], iris.data[:, y_index], c=iris.target)
plt.colorbar(ticks=[0, 1, 2], format=formatter)
plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[x_index])
plt.ylabel(iris.feature_names[y_index])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and the parameter $$\theta$$ is

```
theta= array([-0.52952307, -1.14831508,  2.69829141])
```

Comment: Shouldn't `theta` be of shape (3, 3)=(`n_classes`, `n_features + 1`) (I guess you're considering the intercept, too, in `theta`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that I don't get the dimensions of your `theta` array (it seems to be the output of a binary classification problem, while you're considering a multiclass classification problem with two features and three classes), here's an example of how you can plot the decision boundary, training a generic multinomial logistic regression model:

Initial setting:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

custom_cmap = ListedColormap(['#b4a7d6','#93c47d','#fff2cc'])

iris = load_iris()

x_index = 0
y_index = 1
formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(lambda i, *args: iris.target_names[int(i)])
```

You can instantiate and train a logistic regression model (fitting it on features `'sepal length (cm)'` and `'sepal width (cm)'` according to your setting).

```
lr = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', random_state=42, max_iter=500)
lr.fit(iris.data[:, [0, 1]], iris.target)
```

Then, you can create a meshgrid `[x0_min, x0_max]x[x1_min, x1_max]` of points on which you'll do your predictions; eventually, you can plot your training examples together with the contours defining your boundaries.

```
x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(iris.data[:, x_index].min(), iris.data[:, x_index].max(), 500).reshape(-1, 1),
    np.linspace(iris.data[:, y_index].min(), iris.data[:, y_index].max(), 500).reshape(-1, 1)
)

X_new = np.c_[x0.ravel(), x1.ravel()]
y_pred = lr.predict(X_new)
zz = y_pred.reshape(x0.shape)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.contourf(x0, x1, zz, cmap=custom_cmap)
plt.scatter(iris.data[:, x_index], iris.data[:, y_index], c=iris.target)
plt.colorbar(ticks=[0, 1, 2], format=formatter)

plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[x_index])
plt.ylabel(iris.feature_names[y_index])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here's an example from [sklearn User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html).